# SQL Server 2005 IO Affinity Mask CPU affinity seems to never use 2nd processor

Tags: sql-server

Currently our sql server is usign  IO Affinity Mask and we 're assigning a sql instance to each processor.  What I have a question is the real process handling of sql.

I have two instances (A1/A2).  both processor infinity assigned to cpu0/cpu1 and i/o affininty to cpu2/cpu3.

What i'll notice is if i run a really have procedure on A1 and tap out cpu0, and then try to run a much less resource intensive query on A2, A2 is just as slow as A1, and CPU1 is never really used.

Is there a priorty order? Or is there something else going on.

Comment: I have seen this sort of thing on a server that is disk-bound. Have you monitored the disk queue?  Do you have multiple disk controllers (parallelism)?

Comment: @tgolisch how do I check?

Comment: Windows Perf Mon http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2008.08.pulse.aspx?pr=blog  "PhysicalDisk\Avg. Disk Queue Length"

Comment: @tgolisch Oh I know how to monitor it, my real question is how do i check if i have multiple disk controllers?

Comment: If you have disk inside of the server, check for multiple controller cards. If you are using iSCSI (or equiv) on a SAN, then there is a whole different list of things to check.  Also a different list for a VM.

Comment: @tgolisch Okay can you give me the list of stuff for a VM hosted on a SAN?

Comment: If you have assigned local disk to the VM (server sees HDD as local disk) then check if the virtual disk is defined as multiple disks on the SAN and not one disk for the Host that is shared for different VMs.  If the disk is iSCSI, attached within the VM (not host), then you should keep an eye on NW bandwidth.

Comment: @tgolisch thanks for the pointers, its def not bandwidth and avg disk write queue length doesnt exceed 30

Comment: Did you say 30?  If it hits 30 periodically, that is okay. Average disk queue length should usually be zero.  Queueing only occurs once your disk bandwidth gets saturated.  When you have a few big writes, queuing is unavoidable, but if it gets above zero several times per minute, then you might want to take a closer-look at your SAN config or your disk bandwidth.